# swagger not working after deploying to vercel

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, vercel

When deploying my code I see this under the /docs endpoint (swagger)

[image]

https://python-django-project.vercel.app/docs - link

My `settings.py`:

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = "django-insecure-rjo^&xj7pgft@ylezdg!)n_+(6k$22gme@&mxw_z!jymtv(z+g"

DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "api.apps.ApiConfig",
    "rest_framework_swagger",
    "rest_framework",
    "drf_yasg",
]

SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    "SECURITY_DEFINITIONS": {
        "basic": {
            "type": "basic",
        }
    },
    "USE_SESSION_AUTH": False,
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser",
    ]
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "app.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

APPEND_SLASH = False

WSGI_APPLICATION = "app.wsgi.app"

# Normalnie te zmienne bylyby w plikach .env na platformie vercel
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "",
        "URL": "",
        "NAME": "",
        "USER": "",
        "PASSWORD": "",
        "HOST": "",
        "PORT": 00000,
    }
}

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1", ".vercel.app", "localhost"]

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

`wsgi.py`

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")
app = get_wsgi_application()
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", index),
    path("docs", schema_view.with_ui("swagger", cache_timeout=0)),
]
```

`vercel.json`

```
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "build_files.sh",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": {
        "distDir": "staticfiles_build"
      }
    },
    {
      "src": "/app/wsgi.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python",
      "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb" }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "app/wsgi.py"
    },
    {
      "src": "/static/(.*)",
      "dest": "/static/$1"
    }
  ]
}
```

why am I getting the error in browser?

Answer (score 0):

the app doesn't see your static files. u are on production so looks up folder:

```
https://python-django-project.vercel.app/static
```

think there is no such or is empty. Understand that u had succesfull deployment because i have 404 not found error actually. but to make vercel see static folder i made such things. First I change **vercel.json**:

```
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "build_files.sh",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": {
        "distDir": "static"
      }
    },
    {
      "src": "/czarny_kot/wsgi.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python",
      "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb" }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "czarny_kot/wsgi.py"
    },
    {
      "src": "/static/(.*)",
      "dest": "/static/$1"
    }
  ]
```

}

do u have **requirements.txt**? if not, run:

```
pip freeze > requirements.tx
```

i can't see `build_files.sh` file. I u don't have create it in the root project dir (where u got vercel.json). My file has got to lines:

```
pip install --upgrade pip --no-input
pip install -r requirements.txt --no-input
```

in **settings.py** u don't have STATIC_ROOT which is crucial for static files handling on production. my **settings.py**:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

after such changings u have to collect statics files - locally on development environment:

```
python manage.py collectstatics
```

make sure there is static folder with files in root project directory.

Finnally commit and push to github and statics should work.